# why do some of my .so files on android 11 crash with segv_maperr?

Tags: android, android-ndk, segmentation-fault, java-native-interface, dlopen

I am working on a port of the Yamagi Quake II engine to Android. The game has .so files for different versions of the game logic, which it opens with dlopen() for different mods. the .so for the main game's logic works fine, the game is playable and everything, but all of the .so files for any mod crashes with a segmentation fault "SEGV_MAPERR". they seem to do this when accessing memory in the .so of the ported game, where the main() function is. here is an example segfault:

```
04-03 01:52:42.979 25861 25889 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6ae54822b5f32a in tid 25889 (SDLThread), pid 25861 (SDLActivity)
04-03 01:52:43.040 25936 25936 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
04-03 01:52:43.040   917   917 I tombstoned: received crash request for pid 25889
04-03 01:52:43.041 25936 25936 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 25861 (target tid = 25889)
04-03 01:52:43.056 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-03 01:52:43.056 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/taimen/taimen:11/RP1A.201005.004.A1/6934943:user/release-keys'
04-03 01:52:43.057 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : Revision: 'rev_10'
04-03 01:52:43.057 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
04-03 01:52:43.057 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-04-03 01:52:43-0700
04-03 01:52:43.057 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : pid: 25861, tid: 25889, name: SDLThread  >>> org.echoline.quake2vr <<<
04-03 01:52:43.057 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : uid: 10366
04-03 01:52:43.057 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6ae54822b5f32a
04-03 01:52:43.057 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000006db0f0b508  x1  0000006d5191cf90  x2  0000006d5191ad38  x3  0000000000000400
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000000000000001  x5  0000006d5191ce24  x6  5f726574736e6f6d  x7  6e69207265796c66
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x8  a96ae54822b5f10a  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000006d556bd2d8  x13 0000006d556bd2e0  x14 0000006d556bd2dc  x15 0000000000000000
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000006db1100c88  x17 0000006db1095110  x18 0000006d5168c000  x19 0000006f30912760
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000006f30912760  x22 0000006d5191f000  x23 0000006f30912818
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000006dacf08b28  x25 0000006d5191f000  x26 000000000000000b  x27 0000000000000003
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000006d5191dec0  x29 0000006d5191de60
04-03 01:52:43.058 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000006db10956a4  sp  0000006d5191cea0  pc  0000006db10951a8  pst 0000000060000000
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000008c1a8  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libxatrix.so (SV_Impact+152) (BuildId: c0666b981714b52d06244557ae02680180ed4a6e)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 000000000008c6a0  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libxatrix.so (SV_FlyMove+740) (BuildId: c0666b981714b52d06244557ae02680180ed4a6e)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000000000008ee9c  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libxatrix.so (SV_Physics_Step+1408) (BuildId: c0666b981714b52d06244557ae02680180ed4a6e)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 000000000008f114  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libxatrix.so (G_RunEntity+188) (BuildId: c0666b981714b52d06244557ae02680180ed4a6e)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000000000007f168  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libxatrix.so (G_RunFrame+460) (BuildId: c0666b981714b52d06244557ae02680180ed4a6e)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000000e9e68  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (SV_SpawnServer+1724) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00000000000eaaac  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (SV_Map+1212) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 00000000000e3ed4  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (SV_GameMap_f+980) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 000000000003b624  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (Cmd_ExecuteString+248) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 000000000003ba58  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (Cbuf_Execute+872) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000009bd70  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (CL_Frame+496) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 00000000000499b0  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (Qcommon_Frame+1896) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0000000000049238  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (Qcommon_Mainloop+128) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 0000000000049f60  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (Qcommon_Init+1056) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 000000000007d2d0  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (android_main+880) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 0000000000039b7c  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (Quake2VR::RunMain()+108) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 0000000000039e28  /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/lib/arm64/libyquake2.so (Java_org_echoline_quake2vr_VrActivity_nativeRunMain+32) (BuildId: de1c9afc174fd9682507fe91f60d40e0a6e7b94a)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 000000000013ced4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 00000000001a97e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 000000000031c040  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 0000000000312228  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+912) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 0000000000687d48  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+576) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 000000000002b258  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex] (org.echoline.quake2vr.VrActivity.runMain+4)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 0000000000685960  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 0000000000032034  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~Q7zwr4Li-ZW5yB6WRYqMcA==/org.echoline.quake2vr-B5lP4sN79slxuQs1aCBzFQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex] (org.libsdl.app.SDLMain.run+76)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 00000000006873a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1812) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 00000000000eb7d0  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 00000000003094d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.7618685802058321727)+264) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 00000000006740c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+776) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #34 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #35 pc 00000000001a97e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #36 pc 000000000055c384  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+460) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #37 pc 00000000005ac204  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1308) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #38 pc 00000000000b0758  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
04-03 01:52:43.178 25936 25936 F DEBUG   :       #39 pc 0000000000050150  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
```

the code of SV_Impact is:

```
/*
 * Two entities have touched, so
 * run their touch functions
 */
void
SV_Impact(edict_t *e1, trace_t *trace)
{
        edict_t *e2;

        if (!e1 || !trace)
        {
                return;
        }

        e2 = trace->ent;

        if (e1->touch && (e1->solid != SOLID_NOT))
        {
                e1->touch(e1, e2, &trace->plane, trace->surface);
        }

        if (e2->touch && (e2->solid != SOLID_NOT))
        {
                e2->touch(e2, e1, NULL, NULL);
        }
}
```

the trace struct is returned from the main game yquake2.so, the app seems to crash when calling e2->touch()

I thought it could have something to do with RTLD_LOCAL not RTLD_GLOBAL, but it seems to crash even loading everything with dlopen(..., RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL)

Comment: Possibly a use-after-free? Maybe you could [use AddressSanitizer](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/asan) to help you debug this.

Comment: thank you. I didn't get as far as getting this working but it's good to know about. the problem turned out to be that a variable type was of 1 byte size and needed to be the size of an enum, which is apparently of size int